# На разных страницах сайта скрипт одного и того же элемента работает по-разному

Tags: javascript, битрикс

На сайте 1-С Битрикс применятся  модуль обратной связи Altasib

В хедере создано всплывающее окно.
На одной странице сайта все работает нормально.
На всех остальных окно не вызывается.

Определяется ошибка:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')

Код скрипта модуля Altasib, где выявлена ошибка:

```js
if (typeof ALXpopup_FID21 == 'undefined' && typeof ALXpopup != 'undefined' && typeof BX != 'undefined')
  var ALXpopup_FID21 = BX.clone(ALXpopup);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var param = {
    'width': "40%",
    'url': '',
    'data': {
      "AJAX_CALL": "Y",
      "OPEN_POPUP": "FID21",
      "ELEMENT_ID_ATTR": "",
      "TARGET_ELEMENT_ID": ""
    },
    'cssURL': ["/local/templates/.default/components/altasib/feedback.form/callback_header_slide/form_style.css?164301151147214",
      "/local/templates/.default/components/altasib/feedback.form/callback_header_slide/themes/theme_1159602810ac0b9fa3e4bac7bef13895.css?16430115113150"
    ],
    'objClick': '#form_id_FID21.alx_feedback_popup',
    'popupAnimation': [
      "alx-popup-show-anime3",
      "alx-popup-hide-anime3",
      "alx-popup-mess-show-anime3"
    ],
    'openDelay': '0'
  };
  if (typeof ALXpopup_FID21 != 'undefined')
    ALXpopup_FID21.init(param);
  else
    `ALXpopup.init(param);`
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Comment: Если в этой строке `ALXpopup_FID21.init(param);`, то посмотрите что выдаст консоль `console.log(ALXpopup_FID21)`

Comment: @Greg Увы. Не работает.
Кусок скрипта, что я выложил, как раз из консоли.
Желтым цветом выделена строка:
 ALXpopup.init(param);
А в коде скрипт более сложный - template.php модуля ATALSIB FEEDBACK. И в этом скрипте динамически создаются элементы.
При попытке отладки через console.log ничего не происходит.((

Comment: Так у вас первый if срабатывает или нет? Вы присваиваете переменной `var ALXpopup_FID21= BX.clone(ALXpopup);` или нет? Вы же можете вывести сразу после и перед if все параметры в консоль, проверить присваивается ли значения или нет. (до строки `ALXpopup.init(param)`)

Comment: @Greg FID21 присваивается в админке модуля при создании формы. На странице Контакты скрипт отрабатывает без ошибок, на других нет и в консоли выводится указание на ошибку в строке:  ALXpopup.init(param); При этом блок модуля размещен в хедере. На этой странице размещен еще один блок этого же модуля - FID11. Я его продублировал в футере. FID21 стал работать на главной, но на остальных нет. Реально форма инфу принимает, сохраняет в БД и отправляет на почту, но не работают стили, маска телефона, и, после отправки заявки выводится кривое "Спасибо"
https://xn----itbougdkb5g.xn--p1ai/contacts/

Comment: Весь скрипт не помещается в комментарии. Т.е. я сам ничего не присваиваю.

Comment: Вы в коде выводите `console.log('ALXpopup_FID21');` а нужно `console.log(ALXpopup_FID21);`, у вас есть две переменные `ALXpopup_FID2` и `ALXpopup` от куда берется ALXpopup

Comment: где то потеряли `ALXpopup` на страницах

Comment: @Greg Вот начало скрипта: <script type="text/javascript">

        if (typeof ALXpopup_<?=$ALX?>== 'undefined' && typeof ALXpopup != 'undefined' && typeof BX != 'undefined')
            var ALXpopup_<?=$ALX?>= BX.clone(ALXpopup);
        console.log('ALXpopup_<?=$ALX?>');

Comment: Это не то. вот эта `?=$ALX?>` запись создает переменную `ALXpopup_айдиформы` Сама переменная `ALXpopup` объявляется в файле `form_script.js` На странице контактов у вас [есть js](https://xn----itbougdkb5g.xn--p1ai/bitrix/cache/js/s1/expert/page_84f276fd0c612428bde1830d645526d4/page_84f276fd0c612428bde1830d645526d4_v1.js?16431258739912) с именем `page_84f276fd0c612428bde1830d645526d4_v1.js.....` в котором объявляется переменная `ALXpopup` на других страницах этого скрипта нет соответственно и не объявлена переменная.

Comment: Найдите кто и как вставляет этот файл на страницу контактов (явно же не руками он попал туда), и какие настройки нужно сделать или что исправить чтоб на остальных страницах так же этот скрипт записался (Что то мне кажется дело в модуле Altasib, настройках, параметрах, возможно где то указывается на каких страницах должен работать модуль.

Comment: Вот в [этом файле](https://github.com/nvadim/appetit/blob/de7981e329b3a389fa3827e45e1ce9e404a68779/new.appetit.market/bitrix/components/altasib/feedback.form/templates/.default/template.php) грузятся `form_script.js` разберитесь почему в контактах грузится а на остальных страницах нет. Мне кажется вы где то не выставили параметр (не поставили какой то чекбокс в админке) судя по этим строкам `$arParams['ALX_GET_POPUP'.$ALX]=='Y') && $arParams['ALX_LINK_POPUP'] == 'Y'`

Comment: Зная битрикс, предположу, что где-то нарушен порядок выполнения скриптов. Проверьте настройки "Объединять скрипты", "перемещать скрипты в конец". Это часто вызывает ошибки. Ну и сбросьте весь кэш

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде JS много ошибок и неточностей. Судя по всему к моменту срабатывания JS-скрипт не видит ALXPopup. Должно быть

```
if(typeof ALXpopup_FID21 !== undefined) ...
```

а

```
`ALXpopup.init(param);`
```

вообще - строка.
Оберните внутренности

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

в, например, таймаут 2 секунды

```
setTimeout(()=>{  ...  }, 2000)
```